# Find discontinuities in observational data with R

Tags: r

Data

```
id<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b")
d<-c(1,2,3,90,98,100000,4,6,7,8,23,45)
df<-data.frame(id,d)
```

I want to detect observational discontinuities of each "id".

My expected result is obtain a way to detect discontinuities without using means or medians as a reference.

Comment: What do you mean? What is your expected output?

Comment: What is a discontinuity for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the `diff`erence between a row and the next one within each group is different than 1:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(dis = +(c(F, diff(d) != 1)))

# A tibble: 12 × 3
# Groups:   id [2]
   id         d   dis
   <chr>  <dbl> <int>
 1 a          1     0
 2 a          2     0
 3 a          3     0
 4 a         90     1
 5 a         98     1
 6 a     100000     1
 7 b          4     0
 8 b          6     1
 9 b          7     0
10 b          8     0
11 b         23     1
12 b         45     1
```